# Windows Phone 8.1 Background Agent invokes a custom method severally

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I have a background agent for my windows phone 8.1(C#) which listens to push notifications.
I also have a foreground App and it handles push notification if it is running.
The problem is that the background agent invokes a custom method  `await SyncPushChanges.initUpdate(true);` several times causing duplicate values in my sqlite database.
Here is code for foreground delegate:

```
static async void channel_PushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs args)
        {  
           //Init update from the server
           await SyncPushChanges.initUpdate();
           //Prevent background agentt from being invoked 
           args.Cancel = true;

        }

Code In background Agent 



  public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
            {
                var deferal = taskInstance.GetDeferral();//Save on CPU seconds since we are doing async
                //Get the token and invoke get new data
                await SyncPushChanges.initUpdate(true);
                deferal.Complete();
            }
```

Anyone who might know why am having my method invokes many times?Your help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself.
The issue was that I was not unregistering my background agent and this caused it to work *incorrectly* when the app was updated(In this case when I run the application again from VS2013).
The following code did the magic

```
BackgroundExecutionManager.RemoveAccess();
            //Unregister the Background Agent 
            var entry = BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks.FirstOrDefault(keyval => keyval.Value.Name == "myAgent");
            if (entry.Value != null)
            {
                entry.Value.Unregister(true);
            }
```